# Error when running next build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules, next.js

when I run npm next build, I get this error.
I've tried to google it but I can't find a solution, I also tried installing the
"extract-text-webpack-plugin"

That doesn't solve the issue..

here is the error that it's throwing:

```
> next build

(node:8136) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
[11:17:18] Compiling client
[11:17:18] Compiling server
(node:8136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead
    at Chunk.get (C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:824:9)
    at C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\@zeit\next-css\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:176:48
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\@zeit\next-css\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:171:18
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:12:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
    at Compilation.seal (C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1203:27)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:547:17)
    at _err0 (eval at create (C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at Promise.all.then (C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\DynamicEntryPlugin.js:73:20)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:8136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with
.catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8136) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:8136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead
    at Chunk.get (C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:824:9)
    at C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\@zeit\next-css\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:176:48
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\@zeit\next-css\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:171:18
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:12:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
    at Compilation.seal (C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1203:27)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:547:17)
    at _err0 (eval at create (C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at Promise.all.then (C:\Users\char\Documents\GitHub\Si.Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\DynamicEntryPlugin.js:73:20)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:8136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with
.catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

**Really grateful for answers!**

Comment: Looks like something wrong in your code. Check your Promises and add it in the try catch block.

Comment: @RohanVeer Can I see where it is wrong?

Comment: `extract-text-webpack-plugin` which version?

Comment: @Charlie I guess line number 188 in next_tick.js

Comment: @Abinthaha 4.0.0-beta.0

Comment: Could you try `extract-text-webpack-plugin@next`

Comment: Hey yeah i tried that, got same error

Comment: Also it seems like my friend on a mac can build this np

Answer (score 0):

This plugin needs to be updated. I had the same issue after updating everything went smoothly :)

```
npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin@next
yarn add extract-text-webpack-plugin@next
```